# Datacontact for Castle.Proxies.EntityProxy failed

Tags: wcf, castle-dynamicproxy

How to send Castle.Proxies.EntityProxy via WCF Channel?

How to set the proxy as KnownType?

Answer (score 8):

you're doing it wrong. Don't send entities via the wire. Use dedicated Data Transfer Objects.